# munmap_chunk():invalid pointer

Tags: c, malloc

in header file is declared

```
typedef struct htab {
size_t size;
size_t arr_size;
struct htab_item *arr[];
}htab_t;
```

and have function

```
htab_t *htab_init(size_t)
{
   htab_t *table = malloc(sizeof(htab_t)+n*(sizeof(struct htab_item*)));
   if (table == NULL)
   {
       fprintf(stderr,"Error: allocation failed\n");
       return NULL;
   }
```

at malloc line it throws error:
`munmap_chunk():invalid pointer`
can anyone pls explain why is this happening?
edit: 
n is for size of arr in struct
i ran this through gdb and when the line reaches this malloc it throws me out and says pointer error so it cannot even reach funcion "free"

Comment: What's 'n' 's value?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the `malloc` line that causes the error? I'd expect to see that for `free`.

Comment: Yes, I'd expect to see that specifically if you fail to initialize the pointers in `htab::arr` and then free them.

Comment: Build with debugging then run your program with `valgrind`. It is very good at finding memory allocation errors.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18153746/13422

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the malloc library code often does not realize that it has corrupted data structures until later in the program. So the location of a crash or error message does not always correspond to the actual mistake.

Glibc has malloc debugging modes enabled by environment variables, but I find valgrind to be more useful all around.